# I have been trying web scraping of amazon products reviews, but the data is not getting the data from next pages

Tags: web-scraping

```
Alexa_Reviews=[]

for i in range(1,500):
    link="https://www.amazon.in/Fire-TV-Stick-Alexa-Voice-Remote-3rd-Gen/product-reviews/B08R6QR863/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_show_all_btm?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews"
    page=requests.get(link)

    soup=bs(page.content,'html.parser')
    review= soup.find_all('span', class_="a-size-base review-text review-text-content")
    
    for i in range(0,len(review)):
        Alexa_Reviews.append(review[i].get_text())
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change URL to get next review page.
Now you are scraping 500 times the same page.
Be carefully amazon can ban you if you will do a lot of request in short time.
There you have some code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

Alexa_Reviews = []

for i in range(1, 500):
    link = "https://www.amazon.in/Fire-TV-Stick-Alexa-Voice-Remote-3rd-Gen/product-reviews/B08R6QR863/ref" \
           "=cm_cr_getr_d_paging_btm_next_" + str(i) + "?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber=" + str(i)
    print(link)
    page = requests.get(link)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    review = soup.find_all('span', class_="a-size-base review-text review-text-content")
    if review:
        for y in range(0, len(review)):
            Alexa_Reviews.append(review[y].get_text())
    else:
        break
```

I hope I have been able to help you.